# Modifying awk program that assigns color to sequences based on their values

Tags: awk

I have a AWK script that colors sequence according to the score,
it colors the residues on RGB mode and these sequences can be visualized using some software.The problem is the script colors red for higher score range and green for medium and white for low range.I would like to change it in a way so that it assigns red for low range,,blue for middle,,,or in other words i want the script to work in the other way from low to high not high to low...how do i deal with this.I am a biologist and i have no idea how awk works .Please help me on this.

The coloring is based on this .
http://www.pymolwiki.org/index.php/Spectrum

```
/usr/bin/awk -v aa_shift=$2 '

 BEGIN{
      r1=1; g1=1; b1=1;
      r2=1; g2=1; b2=0;
      r3=1; g3=0; b3=0;

   maxfrq=-1*10000;
   minfrq=1*10000;
   aan=0;

   }

   {
       if ($1!="" && $2!="") {
          aan++;
          aa_ind[aan]=1.0*$2;
          aa_frq[aan]=1.0*$3;

  }

  }

END{
for(i=1;i<=aan;i++) {
   if(aa_frq[i]>maxfrq) {
     maxfrq=aa_frq[i];

 }

    if(aa_frq[i]<minfrq) {
      minfrq=aa_frq[i];
 }
}
    half=(maxfrq-minfrq)/2

   for(i=1;i<=aan;i++) {
    aa_frq[i]=aa_frq[i]-minfrq
      if (aa_frq[i]<half) {
      fraction=aa_frq[i]/half
       aa_r[i]=r1+fraction*(r2-r1)
       aa_g[i]=g1+fraction*(g2-g1)
      aa_b[i]=b1+fraction*(b2-b1)
       }      else {
          fraction=(aa_frq[i]-half)/half
        aa_r[i]=r2+fraction*(r3-r2)
             aa_g[i]=g2+fraction*(g3-g2)
             aa_b[i]=b2+fraction*(b3-b2)
       }
     print "set_color c" i ", [" aa_r[i] "," aa_g[i] "," aa_b[i] "]"
     print "color c" i ", resi " aa_ind[i]+aa_shift " and prot"
      }  
      }' $1
```

the script uses sequences and their score ,for example the first sequence A with score 53.8 will be colored red  and  the lowest scoring sequence L is colored white or any lighter color but i would like to color them red instead and change the order.

```
sequence      no.            score

A             394            53.8314

E             395            12.7202

L             396             4.5191

L             397             22.1270

Q             398             47.6526
```

Thanks in advance for your invaluable suggestions.

Comment: I can't see how this would ever go green, as for scores less than the average it starts at [1, 1, 1] (white) ranging to [1, 1, 0] (yellow), and above the average it ranges from [1, 1, 0] to [1, 0, 0] (red); the red component never varies.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The variables in the `BEGIN` block control your colouring, so you can modify those values to suit your requirements:

```
  r1=1; g1=1; b1=1;
  r2=1; g2=1; b2=0;
  r3=1; g3=0; b3=0;
```

If the score is less than the average score, the color will be somewhere in the range between `[r1, g1, b1]` and `[r2, g2, b2]`. If it is above the average score, it will be in the range between `[r2, g2, b2]` and `[r3, g3, b3]`. How far up or down the range is determined by how far the score is away from the average score.

Therefore, you could change these initial variables to suit your needs; if you want red to be the low colour, blue to be the middle and green to be the high, try changing the numbers to these:

```
  r1=1; g1=0; b1=0;
  r2=0; g2=0; b2=1;
  r3=0; g3=1; b3=0;
```

Comment: I only realised this by coincidence when I wrote my comment on your question... :-)